# Cordova Facebook login integration cordovaOauth

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, facebook, cordova

I am having trouble configuring FB login to work with my cordova mobile application.

I have followed this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1031475/How-to-Integrate-Facebook-Login-into-a-Cordova-App#_comments

```
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I installed ng-cordova and angular using bower. And I put those two javascript files in my www folder along with this code in my index.html

This is what I have in my app.js :

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova']);

   app.controller("OAuthCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaOauth){
   $scope.facebookLogin = function() {

    alert("Click");
    //user your fb app Id.. 
    $cordovaOauth.facebook("1232456", 
    ["email"]).then(function(result) {
        alert(result.access_token);
        // results
    }, function(error) {
        alert("error");
        alert(error);
        // error
    });
}
})
```

And this in my index.html
:

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="OAuthCtrl">
   <label >
       <button class="button button-block button-positive" 
       ng-click="facebookLogin()">
           Login with Facebook
       </button>
   </label>
</div>
</body>
```

The program compiles and runs fine. Although the button is not clickable. Any help is appreciated. Did I install angularjs incorrectly? I've followed this tutorial:
http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/

Comment: What do you mean by "the button is not clickable"?

Comment: The button is visible but performs no action when clicked.

Comment: I Followed this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-into-a-cordova-based-app/ Although I'm getting an undefined is not an object for my $cordovaOauth.facebook when the function is called. I've tried to run the project from that website and i get the same error. Could this error occur because of my dashboard on Facebook?

Comment: Are you testing in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code , I can see that you were not install ng-cordova-oauth plugin. you have to install ng-cordova-oauth using bower which also include all dependancy.

Than  include in index.html

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Dependacy include

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova','ngCordovaOauth']);
```

for reference of complete installation use [Adding google plus login to ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523038/adding-google-plus-login-to-ionic-app/37525072#37525072)